# Редактирование на лету. Добавить select

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть скрип позволяющий при щелчке по элементу информации, например телефону заменить его на input и редактировать.

Сам скрипт: http://jsfiddle.net/8qsFM/

С input и textarea работает, но мне нужна еще одна не мало важная функция select список, для такой же возможности редактировать.

Как я понял скрипт работает следующим образом, если клик происходит по div с классом .editable, то выводится input, если же .editable-area, то выводится textarea.

Как сделать, чтобы если кликнули по div с классом .editable-select, то выводился select список.

Не могу разобраться как добавить функционал. Помогите...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вот это

```
var editElement = $editable.hasClass('editable') ? 
            '<input type="text" />' : '<textarea></textarea>';
```

переделать в цепочку if-ов, и добавить еще одну ветку, внутри которой формироват html для будущего select элемента и далее его уже прикручивать вместо текущего текстового поля.

Comment: немного не понял как это сделать нужно =( я пытался добавить третий элемент, но ничего не работает тогда... =(

Comment: обновленный jsfiddle есть? давайте там продолжим.

Comment: не понял вас...

Comment: "я пытался добавить...", оформите ваши попытки на http://jsfiddle.net/ и продолжим разбираться.

Comment: вот как я пробовал http://jsfiddle.net/8qsFM/2/

Comment: Окей, несколько вопрсов

1) где брать пункты для формирования выпадающего списка?

2) почему не сделали так как я писал в ответе, код

var editElement = $editable.hasClass('editable') ? 
            '<input type="text" />' : '<textarea></textarea>' : '<select></select>';

неверный, ранее это был тернарный оператор (советую прочесть что это), а теперь это неверная конструкция.
Замените на три if-a. Сохраните изменения и продолжим.

Comment: чет ня не как не пойму что в этих if должно происходить...